# McAfee VirusScan Enterprise prevents MSI installation

Tags: windows, msi, mcafee

I'm not be able to install MSI packages downloaded from the [Microsoft Reference Source Code Center](http://referencesource.microsoft.com).

The package installs first a compressed file that gets decompressed by the custom action. The custom action is an executable copied to the temp folder. *McAfee VirusScan Enterprise 8.7.0i* prevents any program to be started from the temp folder.

How can I turn off this behavior?

By the way, *McAfee VirusScan Enterprise* protects its services, so I (as an administrator) am not be able to stop the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the "**Viruscan Console**" and open the properties for "**Access Protection**" you should be able to untick/deselect the option in "**Common Standard Protection**" for "Prevent Common programs from running files from the temp folder"

Answer (score 1):

If you're the McAfee administrator, you can edit the policy to allow execution of the file.  Otherwise, you'll need to contact that administrator.